# My kitty likes to lick my hand/feet but then want to scratch it

Tags: cats, behavior, biting

When I held out my hand , my cat slowly approaches my hand and start to lick it. But if I let him lick or if I move my hand the slightest he will want to scratch my hand . He attacks everything that moves. Why does he behave like that? Does he think I'm a food?

Comment: How old is your cat? If it is a kitten, it looks like the link that @Sonevol posted will answer your question?

Comment: What you describe seems to be a perfecly normally behavior for a cat. It's their grooming habits and it's what they would do with other cats as well.